# Offering help outside of SO

Tags: discussion

What is the general consensus towards providing personal contact details to other SO users to offer further (free) guidance on problems they may have that aren't necessarily specific to that question?

Comment: You are free to over your contact info in your profile if you like being contacted outside SO.

Comment: If people want to be contacted outside of SO, then you might find their contact details in the User Profile page. However, I have some doubt that people would do it for free.

Comment: @bluefeet - I'm the one offering it.

Comment: When I see this it's normally people who've posted a link to their blog and an e-mail address saying contact me. I really dislike this. What form would your method of offering help take?

Comment: I don't have a blog. It's merely to act as support for somebody I feel I could really help out with developing with technologies they're not familiar with.

Comment: @DeeMac If you really want to offer your services for free to users on SO, then include your details (email, etc) in your user profile.

Comment: Not to everybody. I should have specified this in my question. I've seen particular scenarios people could do with some ongoing support.

Comment: @DeeMac There is no way to prevent this from being seen by everyone. The user profile is available to all.  SO doesn't offer a private messaging system.

Comment: Despite that, there's a clear difference in posting my e-mail address in a comment and posting it on my profile. My question is what are the rules/opinions on doing so? Is it permitted? Or is it seen as advertising?

Comment: If your knowledge would be useful to people other than the OP, you could post it as self-answered questions. That would be closer to the philosophy of Stack Exchange, to create public repositories of knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

If it has nothing to do with the question at hand, don't leave such comments. They would be advertisements, and are unlikely to be appreciated by the community. If you wish to state in your profile that you can be contacted for (free) assistance, go right ahead. But don't go posting this in comments.

If it's for support on a legitimate question on the site, I would avoid taking it anywhere else. And not even so much with regards to advertising/promotion.

However you wish to spend your time is up to you, but chances are that the solution won't get back to the site, leaving the question in an unfinished state. Furthermore, whatever you end up discussing and clarifying is invisible to others, possibly causing answers that overlook what you have already dismissed.

At most take it to chat if the situation requires lengthy comments to clarify a question. And leave a comment on the original question pointing to the related chat or its transcript. Then, once completed, the question could be updated with the relevant information.

And even if the question is off-topic, I would hesitate to tell the OP "hey, contact me here and I'll help you out". There is the advertisement issue, but you also set a precedent of "I can ask a bad question and still get help". That's already a problem on the site itself, and adding to that doesn't seem like a good idea.